# Refused To Execute Inline Script Javascript Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-chrome-extension

So I've been learning to make Chrome extensions and for my first real one I decided to make one that plays a gunshot when a user clicks on a page (weird I know). However Chrome refuses to execute the script. I've tried moving the script to popup.js but I get the same error for the audio tag for some reason. Help?

popup.js

var x= document.getElementById('fire');

```
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var x= document.getElementById('fire');
    document.body.addEventListener('click',playAudio);
},false);
    function playAudio(){
        x.play();
    }
```

popup.html

```
    <html>
     <head></head>
    <body>

    <h1>test</h1>
    <audio id="fire">
        <source src="shot2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you precise which error do you get ?

Comment: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ulhrN40fhdE0d7xLFwyQ11r/8OvBfgWlhokn6CdH6Vw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i play sound in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496465/how-can-i-play-sound-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Nope its not, I'm trying to play a sound on the click of any website.

Comment: How about checking the [Chrome Sounds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) in the documentation?