# Sound does not play in background tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've a small Extension which keeps checking for some data on a website.

On specific event it plays a sound file using:

```
document.getElementById("audio-beep1").play();
```

However practically this page isn't the foreground page since I'll be working on some other tab so this sound does not play even though event is detected.

So as I click this tab - sound plays.

Is there any way the sound will play on event even if the tab isn't the foreground one?

Comment: Extensions have lots of moving parts so your question currently doesn't provide the info needed for [MCVE](/help/mcve), it's unlikely to be answered.

Comment: sorry i added the chrome store link

Comment: Certainly that's not what MCVE means.

Answer (score 2):

Google added an update in the past ~6 months or so, a The Great Suspender knockoff called "Tab Freezing" and "Tab Discarding."

That's why you can't play audio in a background tab.  Google has suspended the tab without telling you.  It's also why the second you click the tab, it starts playing the audio -- the tab is unfrozen, and re-loaded.  This is proving to be a nightmare for one of my clients, as they use Incontact MAX, and if Chrome gets a chance, it simply wrecks the VOIP system.

I do not have a solution for you.  Google, in their great and unending wisdom, decided this feature does not need any ability to be configured, disabled, or anything of the sort.  Nor did they ask you if you wanted this function to be enabled.  Truth be told, they appear to be very embarrassed about the unholy amounts of RAM that Chrome uses, and this is their kludge filled workaround.

(You were once able to disable this feature in chrome://flags but they have removed it from said window, and did not add it to the settings menu.)

And no, telling Chrome not to auto discard in chrome://discards does not actually stop it from doing this.

One suggestion I've heard is looping an audio file that is either not making any noise or so quiet it cannot be heard -- like a 1 second loop of dead air.  This might trick Chrome into not freezing or discarding the tab, as it's actively playing audio.  No idea if this will work.  Another I'm planning to test out is using The Great Suspender on the background tab, and seeing if that prevents Google's thing from working.

Comment: did you manage to get the proposed solution to work for you? I'm facing a similar issue. I was wondering if you got it solved so that it might help me understand and solve it too.

Answer (score 1):

Playing sound may do the trick, as tab playing sound is an active tab - but it's an ugly hack and consumes resources unnecessary.

Apparently as of now (12.07.2021) you can Disable tab freezing by this setting: **chrome://flags/#calculate-native-win-occlusion**

Set it to Disabled and tabs freezing should not happen any more. [Here is a source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/146276-how-enable-disable-tab-freezing-google-chrome.html)

Comment: Disabling that had no effect. Did you actually try the advice yourself?